# Set Indian Rupee symbol on text view

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am developing an application. And i need to set the symbol of Indian rupee on text view which is set with the text as amount.

Symbol:

[image]

I am having the font or .TTF file of this in Assets/fonts folder.

And i tried to use it as :

```
Typeface typeFace_Rupee = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),fonts/Rupee_Foradian.ttf");
TextView tvRupee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_rupee_mlsaa);
tvRupee.setTypeface(typeFace_Rupee);

// Tried to set symbol on text view as follows.
tvRupee.setText("`");
```

As above setting font i got null pointer error.

In word file after choosing font and typing **`** we got the symbol. but it is not working in android.

So what steps should i follow to do this...

Comment: Simply use "\u20B9" in your settext string wherever you want to show symbol

Comment: @Akbari Dipali I tried "\u20B9" but it shows box in text after running on emulator. But at layout design in GUI it looks fine.

Comment: @Akbari Dipali Thank you. It is not working on Emulator but i tested it on device. An it works fine on that.

Comment: @AkbariDipali I am trying to set above unicode in text view,it works well in upper version but in lower versions below 4.0 it is shows a box instead of symbol. Can you please help. how to set in all versions

Comment: @Nidhi Yes i got the same problem. It look as box on emulator but on device it runs fine for me. If you face problem then let me know. And if you got answer then upvote and me.

Comment: @ManojFegde Actually on device of lower version I am having the same problem it shows me box instead of symbol

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Comment: Sahi hai ye ekdam correct

Answer (score 233, accepted):

[image]

Hi use this in Strings

For print **rupee symbol**:
      `<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>`

For print **Rs** text:
      `<string name="rs">\u20A8</string>`

Comment: I tried "\u20B9" but it shows box in text after running on emulator. But at layout design in GUI it looks fine.

Comment: Thank you. It is not working on Emulator but i tested it on device. An it works fine on that.

Comment: In my device the first `\u20B9` gives the rupees symbol. The second `\u20A8` gives 'Rs' text. Anyway I got that thanks. +1

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct. There's no doubt. But, I would like to add a line of code to help newbies into Android App Development. To use this resource into your programming, you need to call this string resource through this line of code: `this.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)`.

Answer (score 25):

Use `\u20B9` if you want to print the `Rupee Symbol`
and
Use `\u20A8` if you want to print `"Rs"`

Comment: try using https://gist.github.com/john1jan/a82912fb355771e565bea1720439c5dc . It prefixes rupee symbol and adds even give comma separated amount

Comment: try this.
// Some code here
 child: Text('\u20B9 ${tx.amount}')
// some code here

Answer (score 13):

use on Adapter

```
Viewholder.price.setText("Price: \u20B9"+dataAdapterOBJ.getPrice());
```

Comment: While this code might technically answer the question you would probably help OP more if you explain why your code solves op's problem

Answer (score 10):

Try this, Instead of `Rupee_Foradian.ttf` use `Rupee.ttf`  it will work. am getting currency symbol.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Rupee.ttf");
textView1.setTypeface(tf);
textView1.setText("`");
```

Comment: gr8 answer!!!! keep it up in this way. soon you are going to android programmer into guru!!!!

Comment: I already added this one. I think you did not properly read my question properly. Read code and question properly.

Comment: @ManojFegde Instead of Rupee_Foradian.ttf use Rupee.ttf it will work. i have edited my post check it. let me know any clarifications

Comment: @Muraliganesan : Its not working. As i am getting error as- Java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the above answer  as - `<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string> 

 (or)

 <string name="rs">\u20A8</string>  ` is working for me.

Comment: <string name="Rs">\u20B9</string> (or) <string name="rs">\u20A8</string> both are not working in 2.3 but working in 4.1

Answer (score 5):

You can simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

Comment: Depending on your keyboard and settings.

Answer (score 4):

In 2022, to set number into Indian currency with currency symbol Example:

```
double rupee = list.getAmount();
String x = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en","in")).format(rupee);
```

no need of any file etc, currency in Indian format that is comma after three digit from right with rupee symbol

Answer (score 3):

Copy-paste the Unicode **₹** to **XML** or **Java** and it works just fine. For more info on the **Unicode** refer 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

you can go with the below line of code for Flutter

```
child: Text('\u20B9 ${tx.amount}',
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static String getIndianRupee(String value) {
    Format format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
    return format.format(new BigDecimal(value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet it's working fine in `Xamarin.Forms`

```
 CultureInfo india = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");

 var rupeeSymbol = india.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show Rupees Symbol using **string.xml** then define as

```
<string name="amount">\u20B9%,.2f Lakhs</string>
```

here **.2f** is for show only 2 decimal digit

set programatically

```
binding.txtView.text =resources.getString(R.string.amount, totalExp)
```

using DataBinding

```
android:text="@{@string/amount(model.amount)}"
```

it will show `₹xx.xx Lakhs` modify as your need.

Answer (score -1):

Just simple write this code :

```
Text(
  '\u{20B9}${2880.0}',
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  style: TextStyle(
      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
      fontSize: 15.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
)
```