# Use custom font for rupee

Tags: android-fonts

I want to use custom font for rupee as Indian currency. I do not know how to use custom font. So please suggest me.

Can I directly use it in XML file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Indian Rupee symbol on text view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158754/set-indian-rupee-symbol-on-text-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this as:

Create a folder in assets folder as named as "fonts".
Then use this code as :

```
Typeface fontName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.TTF");
textView.setTypeface(fontName);
```

Hope it will work for you. As it works for me fine.