# Tenge currency symbol ₸

Tags: android, symbols

I want to set the text in code, but symbol(₸) is not displayed on the device
I use TextView

This does not work:

```
liquidationShares.setText("12313" + (char) 0x20B8);
liquidationShares.setText("1 909 993" + "\u20B8");
```

I run the application on the other device, and it works.
Maybe the problem is Meizu

Comment: Refer this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158754/set-indian-rupee-symbol-on-text-view][1]

Comment: I tested the 2nd line and it works just fine , maybe share some more context around it. (Is it a TextView , are you sure the text is not trimmed etc...)

Comment: Might also be a font issue

Comment: It seems like Unicode is not set in your layout. Make sure your layout file begins with this line: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this symbol: `〒` instead of Tenge symbol and it works

It's Unicode Hex(`U+3012`), Numeric character reference Decimal(`&#12306;`) Hex(`&#x3012;`), UTF-8 Hex(`E3 80 92`)