# Android Currency Format Indian rupee symbol mismatched

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Hi In my app Indian currency symbol is slightly curved at the bottom. I Want a Symbol like “₹”.

[image: rv]

```
public static NumberFormat getNumberFormat() {
    String currencyCode = "INR";
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
    numberFormat.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(currencyCode));
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return numberFormat;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158754/set-indian-rupee-symbol-on-text-view

Answer (score 0):

Try this It is working in my code as you need

```
<string name="app_name">Currency</string> 
<string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

you can use also :

```
Textview indian;
indian.setText("\u20B9 10,000");
```