# How to get Euro symbol or Indian currency symbol in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So, I was making this Budget Manager app as I was learning flutter, I want to add a Indian rupee symbol. I had checked the official docs and found a lib called Unicode.dart, however the explanation is not clear. I also searched how to input a rupee symbol in android but that is also not working because the solution is Java or Kotlin specific rather than dart or flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/unicode#-readme-tab-  --Unicode library for flutter

[Set Indian Rupee symbol on text view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158754/set-indian-rupee-symbol-on-text-view) --the android specific

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about this?

```
Text('\u{20B9}'),
```

Comment: is this for Euro or Indian Rupee?

Comment: This is Indian Rupee. "20B9" is a character code of Unicode.

Comment: For the Euro symbol, it is "20AC".

Answer (score 5):

You can combine string interpolation and unicode character

```
Text('\u{20B9}${your amount}'),
```

This is to get Indian currency symbol rupee in your flutter app.

Answer (score 1):

for euro symbol i found solution on the official website
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/euro_symbol-constant.html

I used this code
step 1 : create constant file

```
mport 'package:flutter/material.dart';
const IconData euro_symbol = IconData(0xe23c, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

step 2: Use this icon with your prefered textview
[image]

Comment: Worked for me: For Rupee

final IconData rupeeSymbol = const IconData(0x20B9, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');

Use: Icon(rupeeSymbol)

Answer (score 0):

So I looked at the dart on tutorialspoint.com and found out the solution.

```
main() { 
   Runes input = new Runes(' \u{20B9}'); 
   print(new String.fromCharCodes(input)); 
}
```

The solution is pretty simple you need to create a new Runes and then convert the Runes to String using the String function fromCharCodes(input).

To get any other symbol or Unicode character just replace '20B9' with your Unicode value